# JavaScript fadeOut function doesn't work on second call

Tags: javascript

I have the below function which is working properly for the first time it is called, but on second function call only alert is working .
Can any one pl help me on why the next three lines dosen't work on second, third and so on calls

```
function loginData(){ 
        var form = $("#signInForm");
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/signin/signin',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data){           
        if(data == "Success")
        { 
            location.replace('<?php echo BASE_HREF ?>/profile');    
        }
        else
        { alert("hello");//this alert is coming but next three lines don't get executed second and next all time
          $('#msg').text(data);
          $('#msg').css('color', 'red');    
          $('#msg').fadeOut(2000);
        }               
        //$('#msg').text('<?php echo $errormsg[jserr_msg]; ?>');    
        }                                         
         });                    
    }
```

Comment: could you create jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please could you provide us with a fiddle, so people can check the problem themselves? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I'm assuming you're redisplaying `#msg` at some point, because if it's faded out once, you won't see it display any thing and then fade out again any more.

Comment: jquery's fadeOut leaves the selected element with a style of "display: none" so it wont be visible unless you do something to set the display to visible again.

Comment: In other words the JS _does_ work on the second call :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first call hides the `#msg` element using `fadeOut`.  If you want it to show again on subsequent calls, show it:

```
$('#msg').text(data);
$('#msg').css('color', 'red');    
$('#msg').show();
$('#msg').fadeOut(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `#msg` contents and redisplay it when the fadeout is complete

```
$('#msg').fadeOut(2000, function(){
   $('#msg').empty();
   $('#msg').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example showing how you can fix your problem, I've set Intervals to show the difference between both functions.

The call on the first one is being called, however you're not showing the `msg` again before fading it out again. So it'll look like it's not actually working, then with the second one it displays the message again by using `.show()` before using `fadeOut()`

```js
setInterval(function(){ notWorkingAgain() }, 2000);
setInterval(function(){ WorkingAgain() }, 2000);

function notWorkingAgain()
{ 
  $('#msg').text("ERROR MESSAGE OR SUCCESS");
  $('#msg').css('color', 'red');    
  $('#msg').fadeOut(4000);                              
}

function WorkingAgain()
{ 
  $('#msg2').text("ERROR2 MESSAGE OR SUCCESS");
  $('#msg2').css('color', 'red');
  $('#msg2').show();
  $('#msg2').fadeOut(4000);                              
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="msg"> ERROR MESSAGE OR SUCCESS </div>

<div id="msg2"> ERROR2 MESSAGE OR SUCCESS </div>
```